# how to use verbatim or verb after checking for flag using \ifbool{}{}?

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox

I had no idea that `verb` or `verbatim` are not allowed inside `\ifbool` check. This makes it very limited.

I needed to generate code based on a flag. The code to generate happened to have small part of it which uses `\verb`. I am getting an error because of this.

I looked at [documentation](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) for the `etoolbox` but did not see something so far to help me with this.

Is there a way to use `\verb` as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}%
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\newbool{private}
\setbool{private}{true}

\begin{document}

\ifbool{private}
{
This is \verb|test|  %how to make this work?
}%
{
This is the other case
}
\end{document}
```

Compile

```
lualatex db.tex 
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./db.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(./db.aux)

! LaTeX Error: \verb ended by end of line.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 }

?
```

TL 2016

---

**Update**

Thanks to answers below. 
I have to use `\newbool{private}\setbool{private}{true}` since I set up these already using complicated pre-processing (I read this flag from file during build., etc... and I did not want to change all this code, as it is automated) but with the help of the answers, I found a workaround which allows me to use my current boolean and also use `\newif` to go around this limitation. Here is the final code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}%
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\newbool{private}
\setbool{private}{true}%in actual application, this only set at compile time
              %from reading a file based on makefile command line
              %setting. So it is not hardcoded in the Latex file as shown
              %in this MWE. This is just an example.
\newif\ifprivate

\ifbool{private}{\privatetrue}{\privatefalse}

\begin{document}

\ifprivate
  This is \verb|test|  
\else 
  This is the other case
\fi 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\verb` cannot be used inside a macro argument.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes but I want to use it. I have to generate different code based on a condition.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234292/how-to-put-verbatim-inside-multicolumn-in-tabular#comment554881_234301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\ifbool` is macro, as such `\verb` is not possible inside its arguments.

The standard `\newif` way is much easier, I think (and it works), since there's no argument involved:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}%
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}
%\usepackage{etoolbox} 
%\newbool{private}
%\setbool{private}{true}

\newif\ifprivate
\privatetrue
\begin{document}

\ifprivate
  This is \verb|test|  %how to make this work?
\else
This is the other case
\fi

\privatefalse% Now the other way round. 

\ifprivate
  This is \verb|test|  %how to make this work?
\else
This is the other case
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: Yes, I know, this question is about `etoolbox`, but this is easier, I think (or makes it even possible at all) and it requires no other package.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance what is to be typeset in verbatim, the `verbbox` environment can help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}%
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\newbool{private}
\setbool{private}{true}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\caseA}t&st\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\caseB}Mi#tak^e\end{myverbbox}
\def\mytest{\ifbool{private}
{
This is \caseA  %how to make this work?
}%
{
This is \caseB
}}
\mytest\par
\privatefalse
\mytest
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `myverbbox` can take an optional argument to condition the verbatim box.  Thus, if one defined it as

```
\begin{myverbbox}[\scshape]{\caseA}T&st\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}[\itshape]{\caseB}Mi#tak^e\end{myverbbox}
```

the result would be

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's clever !

Comment: Thanks, but I do not really know all the verbatim I want to typeset and this can change all the time. I can have whole chapters and sections being generated based on this flag, so I can really filter all these out each time. But it is good to know one can do this if needed.

Comment: @Nasser Understood.  Its applicability depends on the situation.